# Isolating a string of 1's in a character

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I need to come up with a function which takes a char and index of a set bit in it and isolates a string of 1's containing that bit.

i.e.

```
char isolate(unsigned char arg, int i);
```

For example:

isolate(221,2) would return 28  (11011101 >>> 00011100)

isolate(221,6) would return 192  (11011101 >>> 1100000)

A lookup table seems a clumsy solution as it would require ~256*8=2048 entries.

I am thinking of examining each individual bit to the left and right of the index:

```
char isolate(char arg, int i)
{
   char result=0;
   char mask = 1<<i;
   for(char mask = 1<<i; arg & mask != 0; mask>>=1)
      result |= mask;
   for(char mask = 1<<i; arg & mask != 0; mask<<=1)
      result |= mask;
   return result;
}
```

But it also seems a bit ugly. How can I do any better than this?

Comment: Your proposition and problem statement+examples seems to tell different stories. Would you please expand on the postcondition.

Comment: I changed formatting. I guess it was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: none of this was tested or even relevant*, but it may be interesting.

Isolating the rightmost run of 1s is easy, like this: `x ^ (x & ((x|(x-1))+1))` (explanation below), so let's work with that.

First `x|(x-1)` smears the rightmost 1 to the right, adding 1 turns all those bits to 0 including the rightmost run of 1's, anding `x` with removes rightmost run of 1's, and finally, xoring that with `x` leaves just the rightmost run of 1s.

Then we just need to make sure that the range we're looking for is the rightmost one. That's less amenable to simple bitmath, but if there's Count Leading Zeros (`clz`), it's not too hard:

```
int shift = 32 - clz(~x & ((1 << i) - 1));  //replace 32 with word size
x = (x >> shift) << shift;
```

`((1 << i) - 1)` makes a mask of the part where the right-end of the run we're looking for could be in (it could also *just* miss the end, but that's ok), then `clz` looks for the first zero to the right of `i` in `x`, then the shifts remove the bits that we don't want to look at.

Apply the first formula, for isolating the rightmost run of 1s, to the result of that to get the run of ones where `i` was in. `i` had better be in some run, or things go sideways (more accurately, it would return the first run of 1s that starts at an index higher than `i`)

*: For this question, none of this really matters. A 2KB table is not a clumsy solution unless you only have a tiny amount of memory available, and even if that's the case, the input is so short that the loops aren't all that bad.

Answer (score 3):

That's a funny operation. The code you've written expresses it fairly well, so would you mind elaborating on how it's ugly?

The details I can see: Given that `i` expresses a bit number in `arg`, there's absolutely no point in `i` being a wider type. There's never a point in writing `!= 0` in a condition. You probably don't want to be redeclaring mask everywhere you use it, nor initializing it twice in a row.

As for the actual spreading bit mask, I can't think of a way that's more expressive, cleaner or efficient right now.